# How to keep previous draw on SWT Canvas use the clock example

Tags: java, canvas, swt

Now, I am reading the book Eclipse4 PlugIn Development By Example, in the first example, the clock on canvas will be moved by using `canvas.redrawn()` every one second, it always shows one second clock, now I want to let the canvas show 1 second clock and after one second show 2 second clock ...  it will be 60 second clocks after 60 seconds.
Now, in this code I use `SWT.NO_BACKGROUND` for the new Canvas instead of `SWT.NONE`, it will be OK in windows, but on Linux it always shows one second clock.

Is there any other way to keep the previous draw on the canvas not clean, and can draw something new on the same canvas.
Thanks a lot.

```
public class ClockView extends ViewPart {
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        final Canvas clock = new Canvas(parent, SWT.NONE);
        clock.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                int seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
                int arc = (15 - seconds) * 6 % 360;
                Color blue = e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE);
                e.gc.setBackground(blue);
                e.gc.fillArc(e.x, e.y, e.width - 1, e.height - 1, arc - 1,
                        2);
                new Thread("TickTock") {
                    public void run() {
                        while (!clock.isDisposed()) {
                            clock.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    if (clock != null
                                            && !clock.isDisposed())
                                        clock.redraw();
                                }
                            });
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`SWT.NO_BACKGROUND` is used to reduce flicker by not redrawing the background but it does not guarantee to retain what you drew before, see for example the last comment in [this Eclipse bug](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=39320). The exact behavior of `SWT.NO_BACKGROUND` does vary between platforms.

You need to draw everything on each paint request.